# Gradle: retrieve only one of multiple published artifacts?

Tags: gradle

I've got an Ivy repository with multiple published artifacts, something like this:

```
/mygroup/mymodule/1.1.1/mymodule-1.1.1.jar
/mygroup/mymodule/1.1.1/mymodule-client-1.1.1.jar
/mygroup/mymodule/1.1.1/ivy-1.1.1.xml
```

If I put in the following gradle dependency line, it retrieves both jars. I want to only retrieve the mymodule-client.jar, but I can't figure out the incantation to make that work. Here's the line I have now. I've purposefully excluded transitive dependencies for other reasons.

```
compile ('mygroup:mymodule:1.1.11') {transitive=false}
```

Gradle docs seem to indicate there's a way to get just a specific artifact, but I can't get the incantation correct.

Here's the contents of the ivy file. Only the module/artifact names were changed and some standard dependency stuff removed for brevity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">

    <info organisation="mygroup" module="mymodule" revision="1.1.1" status="integration" publication="20120111091627"/>

    <publications>
        <artifact name="mymodule"/>
        <artifact name="mymodule-client"/>
    </publications>

    <dependencies> 
       ...          
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Comment: It seems to me that your Maven repository is reporting that this artifact (`mymodule`) is a composite of multiple JARs + an XML file. Maybe the problem lies there, not on the Gradle side (your Gradle syntax seems correct).

Comment: It's actually artifactory, when I think imported an older Ivy repository once upon a time. If you look in the ivy-1.1.1.xml file, you can see it publishes both jars, both are <artifact> elements in the <publications>. The gradle line works, it just pulls in both artifacts and I only want the "client" one.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `ivy-1.1.1.xml` please?

Comment: Do you have `mymodule-client` listed in `dependencies`?

Comment: No, the dependencies are a just couple other jars created in our company, like "myorg-common-utils" type of stuff, which have no other dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to find the appropriate line after a lot of trial and error:

```
compile ('mygroup:mymodule:1.1.1:client@jar')
```

I think it only works because the "client" is an extension of the module name (called a classifier apparently). If I'd had something named differently, I'm not sure how I'd have resolved it.

I found the example that gave me the clue here:
http://scratchpad.pietschy.com/gradle/dependency_management.html

> 20.2.2.2. Artifact only notation An artifact only notation creates a module dependency which only downloads one artifact file. The notation
>   for such a dependency follows the pattern:
>   [group]:[artifact]:[version]@[extension] or
>   [group]:[artifact]:[version]:[classifier]@[extension]. For example:
>
> dependencies {
>       compile "org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.7.0@jar" }

Comment: I was having the same problem with an IVY repo that had the implementation jar, source jar, and javadoc jar artifacts all within the same module. Since the implementation jar didn't have the classifier attribute set I couldn't just that to differentiate it from the javadoc & source. Using the "@jar" notation worked great.

Comment: FYI, by now the official docs for the "Artifact only notation" section is [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#ssub:artifact_dependencies).

Answer (score 2):

The Ivy module descriptor doesn't assign the artifacts to different configurations, hence it's not possible to retrieve them independently. If all you want is to only put one of the two artifacts on the compile class path, something like the following should work:

```
configurations {
    mymodule
}

dependencies {
    mymodule 'mygroup:mymodule:1.1.1'
    compile configurations.mymodule.filter { it.name == 'mymodule-client-1.1.1.jar' } 
}
```

Comment: Hmm this gives me `> Could not find property 'mymodule' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@a5792d9.`

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the configurations part (or have misspelled it).

Comment: The `configurations` section is there, just double-checked for typos, but I'm doing this in an Android project. Does that make a difference?

Comment: It shouldn't (but this has to be done *outside* the `android` block).

Comment: Sure, I had it outside of the `android` block all the time. For the fun of it also tried to move your code from the app-specific `build.gradle` to the top-level one, still no go.

Comment: Hard to imagine. To investigate further, I'd need a minimal self-contained reproducible example.

Comment: For a minimal example please see [here](https://github.com/sschuberth/sandbox/tree/gradle). Running `./gradlew --info clean assemble` there exposes the error for me.

Comment: Ah, sorry. It's `configurations.mymodule.filter`.