# Using Gradle's "Artifact only notation" with a custom artifact name

Tags: gradle, ivy

I'd like to use the [Artifact only notation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#ssub:artifact_dependencies) to download a single artifact whose filename is completely different from the module name. My Ivy artifact pattern is configured as:

```
ivy {
    artifactPattern 'http://host/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]'
}
```

However, the "Artifact only notation" seem to only support:

- `group` (maps to `[organization]`),
- `name` (maps to `[module]`),
- `version` (maps to `[revision]`),
- `ext` (maps to `[exp]`) and
- `classifier` (maps to `[classifier]`, not used here).

The `[artifact]` part of the URLs seems to always be replaced with `name`.

Is there a way to explicitly set in Gradle what `[artifact]` gets replaced with in the URL? In plain Ivy XML I'm able to achieve this by specifying an [artifact tag](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/ivyfile/dependency-artifact.html) with the `name` attibute set inside the `dependency` tag.

My question is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844170/gradle-retrieve-only-one-of-multiple-published-artifacts) except that I do not have a server-side `ivy.xml` file and I cannot use the trick to misuse the `classifier` because my artifact name does not just differ in a suffix from the module name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that the correct syntax to specify a dependency on a artifact whose name is different from its module name is given as part of [this example](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3118?focusedCommentId=19172&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-19172). In order to get `[artifact]` in the URL above replaced with something else than `[module]`, declare the dependency as follows:

```
compile ('group-or-org-name:module-name:module-version') {
    artifact {
        name = 'artifact-name-different-from-module-name'
        type = 'type-must-not-be-null'
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Here are the official docs for that feature as part of the [Advanced dependency configuration](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html#N15F3A) section.